# How to add SQLite to Visual Studio 2022 Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite

When I install SQLite into the Toolbox in Visual Studio 2019, I install the System.Data.SQLite 1.0.115.1 into my Programs Files(x86) folder, and the choose the SQLite.Data.SQLite and SqLite.Designer dlls to my new SQLite tabs in the Visual Studio Toolbox.

However, when I try this with a WinForms app using Visual Studio 2022, I get an error and VS 2022 doesn't like this dll.

I like using the Toolbox, where I can drag a sqliteconnection onto my design time Win form.

What are the correct downloads and steps to add to the VS 2022 Toolbox?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The Toolbox is only really intended for _design time components_ and UI controls, a Sqlite database is neither of those. When you drag-and-drop components from the Toolbox onto the design-surface it's added to the `Form`'s components list, which means the lifetime and ownership of your database "object" is bound to the `Form`'s, which is rarely appropriate except in the most trivial of applications.

Comment: I want to do this, because I can drag the sqliteconnection from the Toolbox, assign it to my session object, assign an ORM class object to the session,, then add a collection that references my db table.  Easy-Peasy and that the way I have done it since VS2013, 2015 and 2019.  It would be nice to do the same thing with VS2022.